# Does PhoneGap automatically generate code for other OS or does it provide only GUI help across multiple platforms

Tags: cordova

I am trying to develop a mobile application for students to interact with a database. Basically, they just enter their name in a textbox shown in the app and click a button, it gets saved in a DB for viewing it later. This is the basic application idea. But the problem is that Students can use any device (iOS, OSX, Android, Windows, etc.) and programming an application for every single OS is time consuming. So I searched around for possible solutions so that my application can be used across platforms and that is where I came across PhoneGap and JQuery Mobile.

So this is my question: Does PhoneGap really make my job easier or will I still be writing the actual functionality in native languages of every OS that I need the app to be compatible? I am asking this because I did look into the already created example of PhoneGap and when I looked at the source code, it had individual folders named Android, Browser, iOS, etc and each of these folders had source files written in the language that is used for developing native applications. So would I still need to write all this and PhoneGap is used only for GUI or does PhoneGap automatically generate all the codes for each platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write individual code for each operating systems. You only write code in HTML and JavaScript. Phonegap / Cordova provides a container app that runs natively on the target operating system and executes your html / javascript code inside that container. It also supplies functions to allow access to specific functions of the device (like storage, camera, gps, etc) that you can use from your javascript code independently from the target operating system.

The folders you see with OS-specific code are deployed together with Phonegap. You normally don't need to change the code in there.

What you do need to take care of for each platform separately is deployment. For iOS for example, this is a very cumbersome task meaning you have to interact with Apple to get your app published in the Apple App Store.

If you don't want to be able to store data locally on the device of the student, but only in a centralized server database, you don't need to use Phonegap at all. Don't write apps for the several platforms, but just write a web application that runs on your server delivering HTML / JS to any browser.